# Error on CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

Tags: php

How do I fix this so my script will work.

Getting this error:

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in /home/halogam1/public_html/xbox.check/xbox.class.php on line 137

Then I ran this script to debug:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('safe_mode');

var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));
?>
```

Output:

```
1string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking but it does look like safe mode is enabled for you.

See the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

The appropriate snip is:

> ...then you will want to read http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-4.php which
>   says "Disabled CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION in curl when open_basedir or
>   safe_mode are enabled." as of PHP 4.4.4/5.1.5.  This is due to the
>   fact that curl is not part of PHP and doesn't know the values of
>   open_basedir or safe_mode, so you could comprimise your webserver
>   operating in safe_mode by redirecting (using header('Location: ...'))
>   to "file://" urls, which curl would have gladly retrieved.

Comment: so how can I disable safe_mode?

Comment: See http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/18424 though disabling safe_mode isn't really a good idea.

Comment: creating a php.ini file in the same directory with "safe_mode = Off" worked for me